# RSSI determination using HM-10

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, at-command, hm-10

I am using an arduino with HM-10 Bluetooth module. I am able to detect other HM-10(slave) in the vicinity of HM-10(master). In HM-10 datasheet AT+RSSI? command is mentioned which i tried with all possible combinations, but i am unable to extract the rssi value. Is there any way such that i can determine the rssi value using arduino on serial monitor. Any relevant code other than the command will be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: i have connected the arduino with HM-10 and using serial monitor i have detected the nearby HM-10 using AT+DISC? command. also using AT+CONN command i have connected my master bluetooth with the slave ones. But when i use AT+RSSI? command its not showing me the value. Most of the commands are working properly except AT+RSSI?.

Answer (score 0):

According to the "datasheet", "This command only used by Remote device query when connected."

Basically, to get this to work, you will need to set your slave to remote control mode with the AT command

```
AT+MODE2
```

*Then,* connect your master and slave.  After this is done, you should be able to send the master the command "AT+RSSI?", it will send it to the slave, which will pick it up now that is in remote control mode.  The slave will then reply with its RSSI value.